# EGit clone dialog: Clean old URIs from content assist suggestions

Tags: eclipse, egit

How can I get rid of old URIs in the "Clone Git Repository" dialog in Eclipse Juno?

If you hold CTRL and the press space bar you get a list of all the URIs you've ever used. I want to delete all but one on of them. If this is only possible by editing a file somewhere, I'd like to know the name and location of that file.

I've tried uninstalling then reinstalling EGit but their still there. Where is this information stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URIs that are available via content assist in the URI field are stored in the following file in your workspace folder:

`.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.egit.ui/dialog_settings.xml`

You can edit it by hand when Eclipse is not running, and it will be picked up the next time Eclipse is started.

Comment: I'm not asking how to change a URI. I'm asking how to delete old URI's that I'm no longer using. If you hold CTRL and the press space bar you get a list of all the URI's you've ever used. I want to delete all but one on of them. If this is only possible by editing a file somewhere, I'd like to know the name and location of that file. When I press the "Local File" button next to the URI text field it just shows my git folder which has nothing in it. So I know that's not it.

Comment: Aha, that information would have been helpful in the question. I updated the answer and question now.